# Lenovo 14ACH5 - ACPI Error on boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, uefi

I can't boot normally anymore... It's stuck at the Lenovo logo in boot. When `quiet splash` is removed I can see the error below.

I still can boot by setting `nomodeset` after `quiet splash` but that does mean I can't even control the brightness of the screen.

Now I booted to Windows (instant regret), updated the BIOS, reboot, UEFI partition f'ed (even more regret for booting the MS crap), created and booted usb stick, fixed uefi, reboot and still same sh!t...

```
ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECSI] (00000000ae16787e) [EmbeddedControl] (20210730/evregion-130)
ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20210730/exfldio-261)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC.ECRD due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC._DSM due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: ucsi_acpi_dsm: failed to evaluate _DSM2
```

This happens with multiple kernel versions, defaults that come with Ubuntu 20.04, 5.11 but also with 5.15

OS:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Hardware:

- Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro 14ACH5 - 82MS001TMH
- AMD Ryzen 7 5800H
- Radeon RX Vega 8
- Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (I replaced the (horrible) Realtek RTL8852AE)

Answer (score 0):

This feels wrong but upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04 fixes it... calling this a solution feels wrong...

Comment: This answer may provide a solution to the problem but lacks any details on how a upgrade will fix the the problem. Please consider including more details.

Comment: I have been unable to determine what causes the error, it doesn't seem to be a kernel version and I was unable to switch/downgrade `acpid` versions